# can't plot parallel coordinates for data frame, what should I pass as second argument?

Tags: python, dataframe, parallel-coordinates

I have a data frame read from a csv file that looks like this

```
    id  area    perimeter   compactness length  width   
0   15.26   14.84   0.871   5.763   3.312   2.221   5.22    
1   14.88   14.57   0.8811  5.554   3.333   1.018   4.956   
2   14.29   14.09   0.905   5.291   3.337   2.699   4.825   
3   13.84   13.94   0.8955  5.324   3.379   2.259   4.805
    ...
```

and am using the command:
`parallel_coordinates(df)` to get the plot

However I get the error message "parallel_coordinates takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)"

I am not sure what I should input as a second argument. Can you help?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `parallel_coordinates`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I looked here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/visualization.html#parallel-coordinates. In the one example they provide they use as second argument 'Name' which from what I read in other places should use data stored in a column regarding the class of the objects. Don't see which column on my dataframe I can use for the same purpose.

Comment: It turns out the second argument functions as a "group by" item, so it requires a feature that allows the classification of all the items of the table into groups. There were two additional columns in the table that I omitted for simplicity ("groove" and "wheat_type") - the second one seems fundamental to solve this. By assigning the second argument to "wheat_type" I was able to have the intended result.